# How do I put plus or minus sign as an x-axis label on a Matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, dataset

For Matlab plots, how do I place plus or minus sign as X tick labels in a Matlab plot?

Currently, I'm using these lines of code but I would like to obtain plus-minus sign (±) values preceding a numerical value on the x tick labels.

x_values = ['+/- 1';'+/- 2'];
set(gca,'XTickLabel',x_values)

Comment: Can you please describe how this question relates specifically to data-mining or data science ?

Comment: Hi image_doctor, I could not find the best "community" to ask this question so I chose Data Science because one has to use tools to perform Data Science in the first place. Would you be able to suggest other places I could post this question? That would be very helpful given that I'm new to this place. Thank you.

Comment: @Raptor StackOverflow is the best place.

Comment: Tough call on questions like this. StackExchange sites overlap at the edges, and I think this could be considered a simple programming question. Matlab is also on-topic for data science. I don't think it's wrong to post here. That said I suspect SO will get you answers faster, and there isn't one here yet. In this case I'd migrate, but not obviously off topic.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for your help and redirection to SO!

Answer (score 1):

You can insert special characters into text using TeX, or LaTex, docs [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/text-with-mathematical-expressions-using-latex.html) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#prop_Interpreter):

`\pm` is used for plus/minus